# CentOS 7 | Can't Start Apache

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I'm running CentOS 7 x86 on a Virtual Machine.
I already installed Apache and wanted to start it, but if I type:

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

it gives me this error:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I type:

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

it gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsxW2.png)

and when I type

```
journalctl -xe
```

it gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB8dh.png)

Please help me. :o

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay so others get help and mine doesn't belong on this site. GJ.

Comment: Stack Overflow is specifically meant for programming. This is not programming related. This belongs in Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to map port `3221` to use apache and you have no access of selinux .

**try a solution of these solution:**

> change listen option of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` to **80** if **3221** is not important to you and restart httpd again

or

> `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

and restart your httpd service.

or

> `sudo yum -y install policycoreutils-python`
>
> `sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 3221`

and restart your httpd service.

i think your problem will be ok after user a solution from these solution.